# Calling python script from batch file opens second console

Tags: python, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batch file that runs a python script. When the python script is invoked, it starts a second windows console and then disappears when it is completed. This is a problem because I am editing the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the batch file, but because the python script is running in a second window, it cannot see the edited PYTHONPATH environment variable. It used to work just fine (everything would run in the same windows console). I just installed Vista SP2 and this problem showed up. Any thoughts on how to fix what might be broken?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with Vista for now (it's a work computer). I also tried the batch file on a coworker's PC with a similar setup and it runs fine. I don't know if SP2 is really to blame or if it is just coincidental. I am using the command C:\python25\python.exe script.py. I also determined that the batch file has nothing to do with it. The same thing happens when I just try to run the python script from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like that's it! In the options for all users, it was set to run as administrator. I unchecked that, and now it is fine!  Thanks for your help,eryksun!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the extension of the python script to .pyw, or just invoke it with pythonw.exe?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran it with pythonw.exe and the second window does not pop up but the python script is still being run in a second window (ie. the print statements in the python script do not show up in the main console window.)

Comment: I think pythonw.exe always runs in an "invisible window".  Did you try python.exe?  (which I hope is *not* the same as directly running a .py script - I think the windows dispatch-by-extension magic interferes somehow)

Comment: I am using python.exe. And It doesn't seem to make a difference if a batch file is calling it or if I just run a python script from the command line. Either way, a second window pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the .py filetype is associated to pythonw.exe, therefore causing it to open in a new process.   Find any .py file, right click it, select properties, and check to see under "Opens with:" what the default interpreter is.

Comment: I do get Python.File as the associated application. Here's what I get when I run `ftype Python.File`: python.file="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I decided to reinstall python. If I uninstall and reinstall (I was using the windows installer) in the default location, it seems to have no effect. I cleaned out the registry and reinstalled. Still no different. However, if I install python in a different location (other than the default) it seems to run fine. Something is obviously corrupt somewhere, but I don't know where. So I am going to just reinstall all of my other modules in a different location and go from there.

Thank you all for your responses.